# is this a proper expression? "they are in a recap"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

the students had learned some stuff before this lecture, and now the lecturer is [talking about](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=80) the content again.

the lecturer himself is saying

> we'll start with the 10 minute recap on ...

how do I describe what they are doing? is this a proper expression? "they are in a recap"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest "He's in the middle of a recap" rather than just saying he's "in" one, but your way does work as well.

And just by the way, "recap" is short for "recapitulation" (or "recapitulate" when used as a verb).

Comment: I would argue that, situationally, "they are in a recap" COULD be syntactically-valid. For instance: "Are Bob and Sue coming with us to lunch?" "No, they are in a recap with the boss, going over the details of the disaster that was last week's sales call."